# RegEx for all files except blacklist

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need to alter a RegEx pattern. I currently have this which matches all files ending in `.aspx` including the querystring:

```
.*\.aspx.*
```

I need an expression that matches all except `foo.aspx` or `bar.aspx`.

Here are some test strings; bad:

`foo.aspx`
`http:\\www.mycompany.com\foo.aspx`
`http:\\www.mycompany.com\_app\bar.aspx?param=1`

...and good:

`http:\\www.mycompany.com\default.aspx`
`http:\\www.mycompany.com\_app\index.aspx?param=1`
`index.aspx`

Comment: What you have done matches this: myfile.aspx.bak, you know? What language are you using for the Regex?

Comment: I don't know exactly what language it is, I assume a .Net language as this is from a configuration file for Microsoft UAG Server.

Comment: Can't you have something like `if (!preg_match('/\.aspx$/', ...))`? That would make things a lot easier.

Comment: @user611775 is that RegEx? It does not appear to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On C#

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^.*(?<!(^|\\|/)(foo|bar))\.aspx$");
```

This will consider only the file name. / and \ are path separators.
So C:\foo.bar is equivalent to foo.bar that is a no.

Comment: I tried these in a test app I found and it does not appear to work: [link](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2t53a) http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2t53a May be the app though.

Comment: @Matthew Because that is based on the regex implementation of Flash (it's built on Flex). I gave you a version for C#.

Comment: I tested it in http://organicbit.com/Posts/2002-01-Regex.html RegEx and it does not work either. Am I doing something wrong? I'll add test strings to my question.

Comment: And because it's wrong even in c# :-) Now it's corrected. You didn't mention you had full paths. I had only tested it for "pure" filenames. Now it ignore paths.

Comment: Testing in RegEx it does not appear to work as you say. c:\foo.aspx and /foo.aspx match. Only changing the file extension causes no match.

Comment: I made a change some minutes ago. Are you checking with @"c:\foo.aspx"? Otherwhise \f is escaped.

Comment: That last edit did the trick! Thanks! BTW, tested here [http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html] (http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html)